# How do I return the static data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a project, a course-rating API. We have been provided with a finished angular application to work with it. We're not expected to change the Angular app.

The first tasks I was asked to set up the routes, with one of them being `GET /api/courses route`

Task two then says:

*Update the GET /api/courses route to return static data.
Return an array of object literals with "_id" and "title" properties
You should now be able to run the application (using npm start), browse to http://localhost:5000, and see your static data in the AngularJS application's "Courses" screen.*

I don't understand what this means, where are we returning the data from? This is only step 2 of the project instructions. The mongo database and seed data isn't mentioned until steps 4,5 and 6.

These are my routes set up in my current index.js file:

```
// include routes
var routes = require('./routes');
// setup our static route to serve files from the "public" folder
app.use('/', express.static('public'));

app.use('/api', routes.courses);
app.use('/api', routes.reviews);
app.use('/api', routes.users);
```

And this is my route in my routes folder:

```
//load express
var express = require('express');
//create router 
var router = express.Router();

// Returns the Course "_id" and "title" properties
router.get('/courses', function(req, res, next){
    //Where is the date coming from? 
    //res.json('data/data.json', [{title:}, {_id:}]);

});
```

In the 'before you start' section of the project it does say this:

*"When you’re ready, you can configure the provided AngularJS client side application to use your REST API instead of the in-browser mock data.
 - Open the public/index.html HTML file into the editor of your choice.
 - Change the constants.useMockData property value to false.
 - Run the application (by using the npm start command) and browse at
   http://localhost:5000. If you already had the application loaded into
   your browser, be sure to refresh the page.
 - The “mock data” alert at the top of the page should no longer be
   visible, indicating that the AngularJS application is now using your
   REST API."*

I did that way before I started.

I don't understand what I need to be doing here. As you can see from my route code!

I'd really appreciate any help please, I understand this isn't the clearest of questions, I apologise. My repo for the project is here: https://github.com/judgejab/build-rest-api-with-express-v1

The full project instructions are in the readme.

Comment: You've already included `/api`, so doing `/api/courses` would mean your route is waiting for something to happen in `/api/api/courses` ?

Comment: Ah yes, you're right there. Sorry, forget that error haha. Fixed. Still don't know what the course instructions are asking me for though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're asking you to return some sample data in that instruction.

Just so you will see some data on the client side and to make sure that your routes are working. Like a small test.

I'm guessing that in the further steps they'll ask you to fetch the data from the DB and return it instead of the sample data.

Am I even close to what you want in an answer?

Comment: You're right about the further steps. 

How do I set up this route though? Could you please take a glance at my github repo?

Comment: You already have the route setup. You can test it using some rest client on the browser or using curl. When you make a get request to that route you should see the sample data in your response. Further down, you need to replace that sample data by fetching the actual data from the DB. For that you need to learn about making connections to the DB and firing queries to fetch data from it.